# Deep Learning on GPU

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia, gpu, nvidia-docker

A DGX-1 has quite a lot of power. However, when using it I only utilize 34% of one of eight cards. Are there some points and tweaks I might missed? I know I can't parallelize everything, there is an upper limit. But to be honest, I expected a better performance.

I'm running a nvidia-docker with tensorflow preinstalled. The [script](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/DQN/dqn.py) running is from dennybritz which is quite well used. I ran the docker one one card. Since it didn't utilized the whole card I didn't gave him second one. Would this have any benefit? Of course I could ran multiple instances and pick the best one. But I'd rather have results sooner when having 170TFLOPS accessible.

Comment: For us to help you we need a reproducible code example of what you have tried so far. The reason you're not getting the performance you want can be any of a multitude of issues, from implementation errors in parallelization, to config errors, or just the tractability of the problem you are trying solving. It's impossible to say.

Comment: The code is linked to the word "script". It's exactly what I run during my first tests. Wanted to see if I can reproduce their solution before messing around with it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I use two Nvidia Quadro RTX 8000 GPUs to run a LSTM model. It shows I only use 54% of each GPU. Don't know how to fix this